# how to find optimal threshold from ROC when returned threshold value is smaller than P/R length?

Tags: python, roc, precision-recall

i'm trying to plot a precision recall and threshold graph. Below is a sample copied from another user in stackoverflow. My main goal is to find the optimal threshold value. I know there are alot of similar posts, but none have the issues im facing. Any help is appreciated!

```
def plot_precision_recall_vs_thresholds(precisions, recalls, thresholds):
    plt.plot(thresholds, precisions[:-1], "b--", label="Precision")
    plt.plot(thresholds, recalls[:-1], "g--", label="Recall")
    plt.xlabel("Threshold")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.grid(b=True, which="both", axis="both", color='gray', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

plot_precision_recall_vs_thresholds(precision1, recall1, thresholds)
plt.show()
```

To populate these i use the following code.

```
precision1, recall1, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test_true, y_pred2)
```

however, after this, the i try running the plot but get this error:

**'x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (688,) and (4830,)'**

Somehow, after passing through the precision_recall_curve, the threshold length is smaller than that of the precision and recall values. Any idea how to fix this?

Subsequently, i want to use this function to find the best threshold. I'm not really sure whats the correct procedure, any tips will help!

```
# convert to f score
fscore = (2 * precision1 * recall1) / (precision1 + recall1)
# locate the index of the largest f score
ix = np.argmax(fscore)
print(len(thresholds))
print('Best Threshold=%f, F-Score=%.3f' % (thresholds[ix], fscore[ix]))
```

According to the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html)

Increasing thresholds on the decision function used to compute precision and recall where n_thresholds = len(np.unique(probas_pred)).

but my n_thresholds not equal to len of probas_pred.